# What does 'with gusto' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was wondering if someone could help me with this sentence containing 'with gusto'. Something to do with enthusiasm/passion/verve, but I don't quite get the full meaning of the sentence.

> [The universe is on your side with whatever you decide to take on.] Business ventures, new romances, and fresh ideas will move forward **with gusto**. [It's time to jump in feet first.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With gusto" means enthusiastically.  Its use here is slightly odd, but it seems to mean that "The universe will be enthusiastic about making your fresh ideas work". It says that whatever you decide to take on, the universe will make sure it will flourish.

(Whether to believe that or not is up to you)

Comment: So whatever you decide to take on, the universe will make sure it will flourish?

Comment: I'm sorry! I gave a wrong Vote!  I'm new here, can I undo this?

Comment: Yes, I've added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

***[Gusto:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gusto)*** is an Italian term which probably entered the English language via lyric opera.

> great energy, enthusiasm, and enjoyment that is experienced by someone taking part in an activity, especially a performance:
>
> - Everyone joined in the singing with great gusto.

(Cambridge Dictionary)